# WSO2 ESB - Could not capture the header in the POST message to REST API

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I sent this message:

```
curl -X POST http://192.168.0.179:8280/esb/api/CreateAddressID -H "content- 
type: application/json" --data @evCaptureJSONPropertiesInvalid.json
```

I was trying to capture the header "content-type: application/json" .
This was my configuration in my API Resource:

```
<!-- Capture the payload values START-->
        <property name="contentType" expression="$trp:Content-Type" scope="default" type="STRING" value="value"/>
```

and then I tried to retrieve it in the log  mediator as shown below:

```
<log description="Request Log" level="custom">
            <property name="Content-Type" expression="$ctx:contentType"/>
        </log>
```

Yet when I saw the output in the console it did not appear what I saw instead was:

[2018-12-05 15:15:07,933] [EI-Core]  INFO - LogMediator content-Type = value

Could someone kindly assist? Also thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Both

```
 <property expression="get-property('transport', 'Content-Type')" name="contenttype"/>
 <property expression="$trp:Content-Type" name="contenttype"/>
```

Should work. I suspect the header is case sensitive and it will work when you use `-H "Content-Type: application/json"